# order-blank. what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

a traveling man working over his order-blanks.

what does "order-blanks" mean?

I searched the Net and didnt find any.

Comment: There's not enough context to be certain, could you provide more? A best guess attempt: *blank order forms*, perhaps?

Comment: Yes. It resonates with context, as Google image search implies. Thanks

Comment: [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blank), definition 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/order+blank) defines *order blank* as "a printed form for ordering" and lists *order form* and *ordering form* as its synonyms.